# How to edit a property that is deep within an object

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose there is a person object that has many ICollection
and ObjectType2 has Icollection

So to edit a property you could theoretically search deep with forloops. 
But what would be a better way that is syntactically nice.

For example to edit a property called PP one could do the following:

```
foreach (var item in PersonData)
            {
                foreach (var item2 in item.Staffs)
                {
                    foreach (var item3 in item2.Employees)
                    {
                        foreach (var item4 in item3.EmployeePositions)
                        {
                            item4.PP = "test";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

But I am looking for something much nice such as:
Whether it via linq or whatever method.

Comment: all a matter of opinion in my opinion.. but I can see your point @mason

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var positions = PersonData
                .SelectMany(p => p.Staffs)
                .SelectMany(s => s.Employees)
                .SelectMany(e => e.EmployeePositions);
foreach (var position in positions)
{
   position.PP = "test";
}
```

This is the equivalent to the nested loops.

Comment: Add if I edit positions. Will it reflect back to the original object? Like update pp property in employeepositions...

Comment: @hidden, Assuming the positions are reference types, yes.  The `positions` variable here is a deferred execution Enumerable that will perform the looping whenever you enumerate it.

Comment: @hidden, I updated the code to show the mutation.  Please bear in mind that every time you enumerate positions, it will perform the looping all over again.  The results are not stored in an intermediate list.

Answer (score 3):

If these objects were stored in a database you would almost certainly do a query against the `EmployeePositions` table possibly filtering it by joining back against the `Employees` or `Staff` tables.

If you really need to access all instances of `EmployeePositions` you perhaps need a separate collection containing them rather than continually enumerating through the properties of other objects to find them.

Comment: This is a good point; this kind of deeply nested update may be a sign of a deeper issue that should be investigated.